Why does Mr. Fogg set out on his trip around the world in 80 days?
In Jules Verne's Around the World in Eighty Days, Mr. Phileas Fogg, the main protagonist, interrupts his exact routine and sets off for a journey around the world, with 20,000 pounds on the line if he fails to complete that task.

Stuart, whose turn it was to deal, gathered them up, and went on: "You are right theoretically, Mr. Fogg, but in practice—"
"In practice also, Mr. Stuart."
"I'd like to see you do it in eighty days."
"It depends on you. Shall we go?"
[...]
"You are joking."
"A true Englishman doesn't joke when he is talking about so serious a thing as a wager," relied Phileas Fogg, solemnly. "I will bet twenty thousand pounds against anyone who wishes, that I will go around the world in eighty days or less; in nineteen hundred and twenty hours, or a hundred and fifteen thousand two hundred minutes. Do you accept?"
chapter 3

However, such a rash decision, which entirely breaks Mr. Fogg's routine, is presented as being in total contrast to Mr. Fogg's nature, which is to be exact to the minute on a precise schedule and never deviate from it.

In any case it was certain that Phileas Fogg had not absented himself from London for many years. Those who had the honor of a closer acquaintance with him than the rest, declared that nobody could claim to have ever seen him anywhere else. His sole pastimes were reading the papers and playing whist.
[...]
He had lunch and dinner at the club, at hours mathematically fixed, in the same room, at the same table, never taking his meals with other members, much less bringing a guest with him; and went home at exactly midnight, only to retire at once to bed.
chapter 1

How is that contradiction in Mr. Fogg's personality explained? How can he make such a decision, totally interrupting his exact routine, on the basis of a bet? This can't be the first time that such a disagreement has happened at the club, so what makes this time so deserving of a twenty-thousand-pound wager and total disruption of his life for months?
Of course, throughout the novel, Mr. Fix is convinced that this is because Mr. Fogg is a bank robber and fleeing the authorities. However, this does not, in the end, hold up, and we are left without a clear resolution of why Mr. Fogg did decide to do this.
Why did Phileas Fogg decide that this particular wager was worth interrupting his routine, betting twenty thousand pounds, and traveling around the world for, since he isn't in fact a bank robber on the run?

This is somewhat speculative, but one could argue that it is exactly Mr. Fogg's personality of being precise to the minute and religiously adhering to routine that spurs him to take on the wager. After all, the whole point of the wager is to show that by following a careful routine, and calculating everything down to the minute, one can do anything – even conquer the world in 80 days.
Here is one passage which may support this idea:

“Twenty thousand pounds!” cried Sullivan. “Twenty thousand pounds, which you would lose by a single accidental delay!”
“The unforeseen does not exist,” quietly replied Phileas Fogg.
“But, Mr. Fogg, eighty days are only the estimate of the least possible time in which the journey can be made.”
“A well-used minimum suffices for everything.”
“But, in order not to exceed it, you must jump mathematically from the trains upon the steamers, and from the steamers upon the trains again.”
“I will jump—mathematically.”


The paragraph just under the first one you quoted has some interesting details that reveal a bit of Phogg's state of mind:

A memorandum of the wager was at once drawn up and
signed by the six parties, during which Phileas Fogg
preserved a stoical composure. He certainly did not bet to
win, and had only staked the twenty thousand pounds, half of
his fortune, because he foresaw that he might have to expend
the other half to carry out this difficult, not to say
unattainable, project.

From this we can eliminate the motive of money. It also shows he initially has some doubts about his success, but (probably as Alex noted because of his extraordinary skills), is confident enough in his chances to wager in half of his fortune.
Overall, Verne's narrative focus is mostly internal and limited to Passepartout's point of view on purpose. We don't have access to much of Phogg's thoughts, so the real reason is left to the reader's imagination, but we can hazard a few motives:

The exciting challenge of calculating the course of a time-constrained trip in the face of hazards and adversity. Winning with rationality against the world's chaos. Phogg's love for whist also shows this at a smaller scale ("The game was in his eyes a contest, a struggle with a difficulty", p. 9).
The itch of travelling again as he might have done in the past ("no one seemed to know the world more familiarly", p.8)
Pure eccentricity - most of the first chapter is spent describing what a strange and mysterious man Phogg is, acting unlike all his peers in the high society but also contradictory in himself, mixing extremely rational and irrational behaviours. Maybe there is no other reason for that sudden decision than his own erraticness.


Fogg not Phogg.
